# Implementing a Generic Double linked list in c++

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

I have implemented a fairly simple idea of a double linked list. I don't know what am I doing wrong!
I have tried making the member variables of the node as public but doesn't help. Friend class doesn't help either. What is the nonclass type here?

> d_list.h

```
#include "node.h"
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template<class T>
class d_list{
    private:
       int list_size;
       T* head;
       T* tail;  

    public:
       //parametrized Default constructor
       d_list(T* h=nullptr, T* t=nullptr):head(h),tail(t){}

       //get Head of the List
       T* gethead(){return this->head;}
       T* gettail(){return this->tail;}
       void addnodeastail(T* new_node){
           if(this->head==nullptr){
              this->head=new_node;//this->head will point towards new_node  
              this->tail=this->head;
              this->list_size=list_size+1;
           }
           else{

                this->tail= new_node;
                this->tail->next=new_node->previous;
           }
       }
};
#endif
```

'''

> node.h

```
template<class T>
    class Node{
        private:
            Node* next;
            Node* previous;
            T data;

        public:
            Node()=default;
            Node(T dta):data(dta){}
            ~Node(){}
    };
```

> main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"d_list.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    d_list<int> d1;
    cout<<d1.gethead()<<endl;
    cout<<d1.gettail()<<endl;
    int var=20;
    int* n1= &var;
    int var2 =40;
    int* n2= &var2;
    d1.addnodeastail(n1);
    d1.addnodeastail(n2);
    cout<<d1.gethead()<<endl;
    cout<<d1.gettail()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Error which I am receiving is something like

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:
d_list.h: In instantiation of 'void d_list<T>::addnodeastail(T*) [with T = int]':
main.cpp:14:24:   required from here
d_list.h:28:29: error: request for member 'next' in '*((d_list<int>*)this)->d_list<int>::tail', which is of non-class type 'int'
   28 |                 this->tail->next=new_node->previous;
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
d_list.h:28:44: error: request for member 'previous' in '* new_node', which is of non-class type 'int'
   28 |                 this->tail->next=new_node->previous;
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Why is your `main` program trying to add pointers to a `d_list<int>`?  Shouldn't it simply call the `add` function using `int` values, and the linked list class takes care of the details?

Comment: Pretty much all your pointers should point to `Node<T>` instead of to `T`.

Comment: If I may ask, why are you trying to implement a double-linked list in C++?

Comment: I would expect something like; `d_list<int> d1; d1.add(10); d1.add(20); d1.add(30);` and expect to see `d_list` have 3 items in the list.  The `main` shouldn't be playing around with pointers, `Nodes`, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Got it! Will try to implement the same. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone please recommend some books or tutorials for data structures from scratch?

Comment: @Tushar The issue of using C++ to build the data structure is that you will be fighting two battles.  The first being the actual high-level details of the data structure, and the second being the language.   You could know what a linked-list is inside and out, but implementing it in C++ is a challenge to get correct.  You have memory allocation / handling issues, copy semantics to consider, etc.  In my experience, I have yet to see a student or beginner get a linked-list coded correctly using C++ to the point where it is usable without bugs appearing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand, but recently I have been learning c++ and was amused by its power and that is why I am trying to do things in c++. Please recommend some kind of tutorial or book which can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `head` and `tail` shouldn't be `T`, but rather `node<T>`:

```
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* tail;
```

Remember, `T` is the type of object you want to hold in your list. It has no link associated with it. So if you do a `d_list<int>` currently as written, the templated code will look something like this:

```
int* head;
int* tail;
```

These are not linked to each other, this is just a pointer to an `int` (or a list of `int`s if you used something like `new`). To create a link, you need to use `Node` so o matter where in memory they are stored, they will have a logical connection. That way, `d_list<int>` would look something like this instead:

```
Node<int>* head;
Node<int>* tail;
```

This will let you use nodes to develop a logically connected list of `int`s, which is exactly what you want for a linked list.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
template<class T>
class d_list{
    private:
       int list_size;
       T* head;
       T* tail;
```

you declare that `head` and `tail` are pointers to the template type `T`.

That means for `d_list<int>` you effectively have

```
int* head;
int* tail;
```

That makes no sense, your head and tail pointers should be pointers to the first and last ***nodes*** in the list:

```
Node<T>* head;
Node<T>* tail;
```

And when adding elements to the list, you need to create new `Node<T>` instances to hold the data, and add the nodes to the list.